# new existing extension not install in magento

Tags: xml, magento-1.7

i have one error that error will come that time new existing extension add in magento that time error come Fatal error: Call to undefined method domdocument::loadXML() in C:\wamp\www\magento\downloader\lib\Mage\Xml\Parser.php on line 111
i have code error code that code i show in that display

```
 public function loadXML($string)
{
    $this->getDom()->loadXML($string);
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then try to install extension manually using this site just paste key here and download

http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

it will works for you